# Using root and modifiers in translation task

Tags: transformer, machine-translation

I am doing a project of translation task by finetuning `T5` model. I am given sentences in Chinese, their translation to English, and for every English sentence I am also given its ROOT and some modifiers of the root. How can I use the ROOT and its modifiers in order to achieve better results?

I can't think about ideas for how to use this additional information.